# Save selection to a Google Sheets spreadsheet in PDF

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBWDY.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m96B3.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plj5y.jpg)This is my first question. I am learning about Scripts and adapting some spreadsheets of my service in Google Sheets.

Help: I have a spreadsheet that I intend to save to PDF inside the DRIVE. This is OK, I got the code and adjusted them according to what I need. However when it saves, it takes off the outline of what I need. I need to save only between the outline of the lines.

Code Used:

```js
function generatePDF() {
  var sheetName = "NOTA DE CREDITO ASSOCIAÇÃO SAUDE";
  var folderID = "atalho google drive";
  var pdfName = "NC_SAUDE " + Date();

  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("atalho google drive");

  //Copy whole spreadsheet
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))

  //delete redundant sheets
  var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName) {
      destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }

  var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  //repace cell values with text (to avoid broken references) 
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1, sourceSheet.getMaxRows(), sourceSheet.getMaxColumns());
  var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getDisplayValues();
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
  destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);

  //save to pdf
  var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

  //Delete the temporary sheet
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
```

}

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `the outline of the lines.` of `I need to save only between the outline of the lines.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Hello, how are you:
Select and save specific area.

Comment: I saved the model image.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From them, you select the range (cells) and you want to export the selected range as a PDF file. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes, save the range.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand that you want to export the selected range as a PDF file. 1. In this case, `var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];` is the sheet you want to export? 2. You select the range you want to export before you run the script?

Comment: Hi ! Do you specifically want to specifically use Apps Script for this? Otherwise you could simply select the range you want to export and then head over in the menu to **File->Download->Download as PDF** and in the emerging window select under **Export** the option **Selected Cells**. Please let me know if you specifically want a scripted answer for this :)

Comment: @MateoRandwolf
 I need it via code. I created a form.

Comment: @Tanaike

I added the image of the interval that I need to save in pdf. When I save it he takes everything he has on the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You were missing the step where you only have a single sheet on the new spreadsheet and where you paste the range values in the first cell of the sheet's spreadsheet.

Here is the script that solves this problem. It is self explained with comments:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Get the range of cells you want to export 
  var rangeValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('D10:F13').getValues();
  // Get the Drive folder you want to store your PDF to. Otherwise use root folder (if you dont mind about this)
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDERID');
  
  // Create a blank spreadsheet to be able to export just the range
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('PDF');
  
  // Check first if the sheet you are going to create exists. Otherwsie create it and copy paste the range
  // we want to export as PDF in the first values of the sheet. I.e if our range is 5 rows and 6 columns we want
  // it to be copied from A1 to F5 for example. Then we can hide the rest of columns and rows and export 
  // what we have left
  var sheet2 = destSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet2');
  if(!sheet2){
    destSpreadsheet.insertSheet('sheet2').getRange('A1:C4').setValues(rangeValues);
    var sheet2 = destSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('sheet2');
  }
  
  // Hide all the rows and columns that do not have content 
  sheet2.hideRows(sheet2.getLastRow()+1, sheet2.getMaxRows()-sheet2.getLastRow());
  sheet2.hideColumns(sheet2.getLastColumn()+1, sheet2.getMaxColumns()-sheet2.getLastColumn());
  // Delete the first sheet that is automatically created when you create a new spreadsheet
  destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(destSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'));
  
  // Export our new spreadsheet to PDF
  var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName('pdf');
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
  
  //Delete the spreadsheet we created to export this range. 
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}
```

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: hello, You are saving all spreadsheets in pdf. Keep saving outside where I need to.